# jQuery hide onLoad not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-rails

Rails 5.1 App, using jquery-rails (loading jQuery 1.12.4). I have a function included in the header of a page that was working. I fixed a missing JS file function error unrelated to this and now it looks right while loading and then flips (looks to be at the time it loads favicons in the Rails console). If I cause the missing method error (in a client side validation JS) then this code works properly, which means there's something else afoot to me.

*Once it's flipped, the `.togglebutton` doesn't function (this fixed with Josh's comment below)*

This behavior can be seen live here: https://www.patchvault.org/lodges

The function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nni').toggleClass('hidden');
  $('.togglebutton').click(function() {
    $('.nni').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.togglebutton').toggleClass('nodisplay');
  });
});
```

Updated function after Josh's comments below (and other SO searching):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).load(function () {
    $('.nni').toggleClass('hidden');
    $(document).on('click', '.togglebutton', function() {
      $('.nni').toggleClass('hidden');
      $('.togglebutton').toggleClass('nodisplay');
    });
  });
});
```

Toggle Button code:

```
<div id="button_functions">
    <a class="togglebutton nodisplay" href="javascript:;">Hide No Known Issue Lodges (16)</a>
    <a class="togglebutton" href="javascript:;">Show No Known Issue Lodges (16)</a>
  </div>
```

relevant CSS:

```
.hidden,
.nodisplay { display: none; }
```

LI (example):

```
<ul class="lodge-list">
  <li class="lodge nni">
      <a href="/lodges/2a-trenton"><img alt="No known issues for 2A" style="width: 200px;" src="/assets/no_known_issues@2x.png"></a>

    <p class="lodge-name">
      <a href="/lodges/2a-trenton"><b>2</b> Trenton</a><br>
      <span>
        (2A)
      </span>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li class="lodge ">
        <a href="/lodges/2-5a-ntiasohen-gattopuin"><img alt="2.5 Ntiasohen Gattopuin" class="featured-image-home" src="https://patchvault.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/issue/image/4114/list_Fish_Flap_1992.jpg?X-Amz-Expires=600&amp;X-Amz-Date=20180711T120316Z&amp;X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIOPOW7QY5HS62KZA/20180711/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=19a5afd4d18ccb7951c756a4916aef200026ac447f45452ca66427480a6f0d27"></a>
      <!-- <= link_to image_tag(lodge.issues.first.image_url(:list)),
            lodge_path(
              lodge.slug
            ) %> -->

    <p class="lodge-name">
      <a href="/lodges/2-5a-ntiasohen-gattopuin"><b>2.5</b> Ntiasohen Gattopuin</a><br>
      <span>
        (2.5A)
      </span>
    </p>
  </li>
  [ Other lodges are one of these two styles ]
</ul>
```

which is currently running. If I reintroduce the console error (rails client-side form validations missing file), it works. But there's got to be something else going on that I'm doing wrong here to cause this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you add some html ?

Comment: Try using `$(document).on('click', '.togglebutton', function() { ... });`

Comment: Have one JS error on page load in browser console.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null` may be resolving this will solve your problem.

Comment: @KiranShahi added button and UL/LI html, as well as relevant CSS hiding property.

Comment: @JoshBrody Thanks. That fixes the button not working when the error occurs, but the items that should be hidden at onLoad are still popping up.

Comment: @SujayGavhane Thanks for catching that non-logged-in error for me. Fixed the conditional wrapper on that (as the HTML wasn't rendered with the class that other JS function was looking for). Updated code deployed to production. Original error (first load items with .nni show up) is persisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the way I was eventually able to solve this was more simple than anything else:

I had the rails ERB that sets "nni" as a class set "nni hidden" instead. So both of those classes apply on page load. From there, the JS is simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '.togglebutton', function() {
    $('.nni').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.togglebutton').toggleClass('nodisplay');
  });
});
```

Probably a way to make that simpler/cleaner as well, but it works.